# Unexpected list index affects word option for difflib.get_close_matches()

Tags: python, list, indexing

Question: I am required to use this indexing of tokens in my difflib call:
`difflib.get_close_matches(tokens[0], jobList, n=1, cutoff=0.85)` in order to get my required output. If I use what I expect. Which is `tokens[j]` then my output is affected by having the token `Asst` still appearing before the address `Wyndrum`. Why?

```
# Short test removes job descriptions from in front of address trailing address strings
testList = ['21 Sharp Crescent _Wainuiomata Shop Asst','Shop Asst Wyndrum Avenue _Lower_Hutt Housewife','Housewife']
jobList = ['Asst','Housewife','Shop']

import difflib

newList = []
for i in range(len(testList)):
    tokens = testList[i].split()
    for j in range(len(tokens)):
        print("tokens[j]",tokens[j],"tokens[0]",tokens[0])
        result = difflib.get_close_matches(tokens[0], jobList, n=1, cutoff=0.85)
        if result:
            while tokens and tokens[0] == result[0]:
                    tokens.pop(0)               
        else:
            newString = ' '.join(tokens)
            newList.append(newString)
            break

for i in range(len(newList)):
    print(newList[i])
```

Expected/Correct Output

```
21 Sharp Crescent _Wainuiomata Shop Asst
Wyndrum Avenue _Lower_Hutt Housewife
```

Debug print lines

```
tokens[j] 21 tokens[0] 21
tokens[j] Shop tokens[0] Shop
tokens[j] Wyndrum tokens[0] Asst
tokens[j] _Lower_Hutt tokens[0] Wyndrum
tokens[j] Housewife tokens[0] Housewife
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: inside `for j in range(len(tokens))` you runs `tokens.pop(0)` which removes items from list - so later `for j ...` and `token[j]` may try to get element which doesn't exists on list. it calculate `len(tokens)` only once - at start - and later it doesn't check if list is shorter or longer. You shouldn't use `token.pop()` in `for ... in range(len(token))`. You should run `.pop()` on clone of `tokens` - `clone = tokens.copy()`, Or you should work use `while` instead of `for`

Comment: there is rule: if you use `for`-loop to iterate some list then don't remove elements from this list (don't use `remove()` or `pop()`). When you remove element then other elements moves on list - they change index - and later `for` skip some element because it doesn't know that elements moved. You should work on copy of token - like `for tok in tokens.copy()`, or you should create new list and move elements which you want to keep instead of removing elements which you want to skip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is rule in Python: if you use `for`-loop to iterate some `list` then don't remove elements from this list - don't use `remove()` or `pop()`. Work on copy of original list or create new list with elements which you want to keep.

When you remove element from list then other elements move on list - and they change indexes. And later `for` skips some element because it doesn't know that elements changed indexes.

You should work on copy of tokens - `tokens.copy()`

```
tokens = text.split()
copy = tokens.copy()   # <-- create copy

for j in range(len(copy)):  # <-- use copy
    print("tokens[j]", copy[j], "tokens[0]", tokens[0]) # <-- use copy
```

---

Full working code with other changes:

```
import difflib

# PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
test_list = [
    '21 Sharp Crescent _Wainuiomata Shop Asst',
    'Shop Asst Wyndrum Avenue _Lower_Hutt Housewife',
    'Housewife'
]
job_list = ['Asst', 'Housewife', 'Shop']

new_list = []  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables

for text in test_list:
    print(f'\n>>> text: {text} <<<\n')
    
    tokens = text.split()
    copy = tokens.copy()
    
    # loop copy of tokens.
    for j in range(len(copy)):
    #for j, tok in enumerate(tokens.copy()):
        print(f"tokens[j]: {copy[j]:10} | tokens[0]: {tokens[0]}")
        
        #result = difflib.get_close_matches(tokens[0], job_list, n=1, cutoff=0.85)
        result = difflib.get_close_matches(copy[j], job_list, n=1, cutoff=0.85)
        
        if result:
            if tokens[0] == result[0]:
                print('   remove:', tokens.pop(0))
        else:
            break

    new_list.append(' '.join(tokens))

print('\n--- results ---\n')

for old, new in zip(test_list, new_list):
    print(old, '--->', new)
```

Result:

```
>> text: 21 Sharp Crescent _Wainuiomata Shop Asst <<<

tokens[j]: 21         | tokens[0]: 21

>>> text: Shop Asst Wyndrum Avenue _Lower_Hutt Housewife <<<

tokens[j]: Shop       | tokens[0]: Shop
   remove: Shop
tokens[j]: Asst       | tokens[0]: Asst
   remove: Asst
tokens[j]: Wyndrum    | tokens[0]: Wyndrum

>>> text: Housewife <<<

tokens[j]: Housewife  | tokens[0]: Housewife
   remove: Housewife

--- results ---

21 Sharp Crescent _Wainuiomata Shop Asst ---> 21 Sharp Crescent _Wainuiomata Shop Asst
Shop Asst Wyndrum Avenue _Lower_Hutt Housewife ---> Wyndrum Avenue _Lower_Hutt Housewife
Housewife --->
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank you. I have learnt from your code/comments. The rules make sense.